# how to retrieve data from arraylist which store in object array formate in c#

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList aStru = new ArrayList();
aStru.Add(new Object[] { "board_id"  , "N" , LEN_ID, 0, "PRIMERY_KEY"});
aStru.Add(new Object[] { "board_name", "VC", 50    , 0, ""           });
aStru.Add(new Object[] { "description","VC", 100   , 0, ""           });
```

I try to retrieve data

```
for( nCtr=0; nCtr < (aStru.count); nCtr++ )
{
Object[] obj = (Object)aStru[nCtr];
}
```

please help me, how i can retrieve data from this format of arraylist in c#.

Comment: It's 2015, you should learn about classes and `List<T>`, this would be much easier.

Comment: @Blorgbeard you could've rephrase your advice in a professional manner

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not OP's paid consultant, and I don't think it was *that* rude - it wasn't intended to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `Object[] obj = (Object[])aStru[nCtr]`